# Remove stopwords based on a long list

Tags: r, tm

I have a dataframe with 60000 rows/phrase which I would like to use as stopwords and remove from text.

I use tm package and I use this line, after I read the csv file with the list of stopwords:

```
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, df$mylistofstopwords)
```

but I receive this error:

```
In addition: Warning message:
In gsub(sprintf("(*UCP)\\b(%s)\\b", paste(sort(words, decreasing = TRUE),  :
  PCRE pattern compilation error
    'regular expression is too large'
    at ''
```

Is there any problem because the list is to big? Is there anything I could make to fix it?

Comment: Split the list and call `tm_map` twice with two different `removeWords` lists?

Comment: @MrFlick I tried to spilt the full list but again the problem is the same. I tried only the first 2000 rows and it works. I just wonder if there is a more efficient code solution and possible faster

Comment: Are these very long words? What's `range(nchar(df$mylistofstopwords))`?

Comment: @MrFlick I tried to type the `range(nchar(df$mylistofstopwords))` but I receive this error: `Error in nchar(df$mylistofstopwords) : 
  'nchar()' requires a character vector`

Comment: Is that column not a character class? What does `class(df$mylistofstopwords)` return? Maybe `range(nchar(as.character(df$mylistofstopwords)))’ or the `mean()`

Comment: @MrFlick the return of class is "factor". The `range(nchar(df$mylistofstopwords))` the same error as previously and mean returna this ` [1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(df$mylistofstopwords) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA`

Answer (score 2):

You could probably resolve your issue by splitting the stopword list into multiple parts, something like the following:

```
chunk <- 1000
i <- 0
n <- length(df$mylistofstopwords)
while (i != n) {
    i2 <- min(i + chunk, n)
    corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, df$mylistofstopwords[(i+1):i2])
    i <- i2
}
```

Or, you could just use a package that can handle long stopword lists. *corpus* is one such package. *quanteda* is another. Here's how to get a document-by-term matrix in *corpus*

```
library(corpus)
x <- term_matrix(corpus, drop = df$mylistofstopwords)
```

Here, the input argument `corpus` can be a *tm* corpus.